# MatPlotLib Picker for multiple arrays in one plot

Tags: matplotlib

I am plotting two arrays, each with 10 points.

e.g. l,m and l,n

```
l= ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
m = ([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100])
n = (11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,101])
```

The picker example on this forum allowed me to pick 1 set of values (e.g. 3,30) and its index from m. What I'd like to do is modify it such that it can pick any values and it's corresponding array e.g. l,n [7], 8,81. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Also, is it possible to have a line plot? The earlier example worked with scatter. If it's scatter plot can I color the dots differently?

Thank you

Comment: Which "picker example" are you referring to?  It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking...

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/pick_event_demo.html I am referring to the scatter plot section.

Comment: Can you show code that you have used to try this? That would help make clearer what you're trying to do.